# BeautifulSoup : create and insert self closing tag between a tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

I am parsing html files and replacing specific links with new tags.

Python Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sample='''<a href="{Image src='https://google.com' link='https://google.com'}" >{Image src='https://google.com' link='google.com'}</a>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(sample)
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    x=BeautifulSoup('<ac:image><ri:attachment ri:filename="somefile"/> </ac:image>')
    a=a.replace_with(x)

print(soup)
```

**Actual Output:**

```
<ac:image><ri:attachment ri:filename="somefile"></ri:attachment> </ac:image>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<ac:image><ri:attachment ri:filename="somefile" /></ac:image>
```

The self closing Tags are automatically getting converted. The destination strictly needs self closing tags.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to include the code, pls add it to the post.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post input/your code ?

Comment: @Sushanth , added code with desired and Actual Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct self closing tags, use parser `xml` when creating new soup that is going to replace old tag.

Also, to preserve `ac` and `ri` namespaces, `xml` parser requires to define `xmlns:ac` and `xmlns:ri` parameters. We define these parameters in a dummy tag that is removed after processing.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml
txt = '''
<div class="my-class">
    <a src="some address">
        <img src="attlasian_logo.gif" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="my-class">
    <a src="some address2">
        <img src="other_logo.gif" />
    </a>
</div>
'''

template = '''
<div class="_remove_me" xmlns:ac="http://namespace1/" xmlns:ri="http://namespace2/">
<ac:image>
  <ri:attachment ri:filename="{img_src}" />
</ac:image>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a'):
    a=a.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(template.format(img_src=a.img['src']), 'xml'))  # <-- select `xml` parser, the template needs to have xmlns:* parameters to preserve namespaces

for div in soup.select('div._remove_me'):
    dump=div.unwrap()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="my-class">
 <ac:image>
  <ri:attachment ri:filename="attlasian_logo.gif"/>
 </ac:image>
</div>
<div class="my-class">
 <ac:image>
  <ri:attachment ri:filename="other_logo.gif"/>
 </ac:image>
</div>
```

Comment: Throwing below error for **'xml'** parser at **replace_with** line
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 245, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Comment: @Yash Yes, you need to install `lxml` module to your Python.

Comment: ```import xml```  did the job.